# Connect with public IP (ok) & Domain (not ok) EC2 Windows Instance

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, dns, xampp

here is what I did so far:

1. I have setup a windows 10 instance
2. I assigned an Elastic IP
3. I added rules to the security group

   ```
   HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0 
   Custom TCP Rule TCP 7474 0.0.0.0/0
   MYSQL/Aurora TCP 3306 0.0.0.0/0
   ```
4. I assigned the public IP to the domain in the hosted zone as A record
5. I installed XAMPP 3.2.2
6. I made sure in httpd.conf

   ```
   # Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```

   is active
7. In httpd-vhosts.conf I entered

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/my_app"
     ServerName myapp.cloud
     ServerAlias www.myapp.cloud
     <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/my_app">
       AllowOverride All
       Require all Granted
     </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
   ```
8. I also changed hosts on the Windows Server (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)

   ```
     127.0.0.1 myapp.cloud
   ```
9. I rebooted the system
10. I started Apache via XAMPP Panel

Results:

1. I can access myapp.cloud local on the server with RDP session
2. I can access the public IP from outside and get the XAMPP screen
3. I can also access publicIP/my_app and get my application
4. A ping confirms that port 80 is obviously open (otherwise I wouldnt see the XAMPP screen as well)
5. I CANNOT access the application by typing myapp . cloud - this results in

   ```
    ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
   ```
6. Also Port 7474 seems NOT open although there is an entry
   A port check (http://ping.eu/port-chk/) gives:

   ```
    myapp.cloud:80 is open
    myapp.cloud:3306 is open
    myapp.cloud:7474 is CLOSED
   ```

Apparently the domain resolves correct as a DNS check returns the correct IP

So my issues:

1. Port 7474 isnt open although set in security
2. Cant access myapp.cloud although DNS seems right and port 80 is open and listens. (tested on FF and Chrome)

Any hints are very appreciated,
thanks.

######## EDIT ############# 09-11-2017

The problem of the unconnected IP is solved. It was a wrong DNS setting in my internal router - the router didnt renewed the IP settings. So Internet said DNS is correct but private network didnt - I flushed DNS on my PC but forgot to check the router and there was the problem.

Still struggling with the ports ..

Comment: is port 7474 open in windows firewall?

Comment: Hi, the windows FW has been switched of for testing purposes. So I would assume that she is not in the way. I need to dig further :(

Comment: Is there any app listening on port 7474?

Comment: Hi Dusan, yes the port is dediacted for an app. Using localhost:7474 this app is answering correct. The Wndows Firewall has a rule for this port which allows 7474 and AWS security group as well.

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -na | findstr 7474`, from windows command line?

Comment: It says:  TCP    127.0.0.1:7474         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: `127.0.0.1:7474` means that the application is listening only on loopback ("localhost") interface, that is why the port is not reachable from outside. That should be configurable in application settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that hint was gold :) Enjoy the weekend as I will do now :P